# Dirichlet predictive distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, dirichlet-distribution

I need to derive a posterior predictive density for observation T+1 given that the posterior distribution of $(x_{1}, x_{2}, 1-x_{1}-x_{2})$ is a Dirichlet distribution with parameter $(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3})$.

For precision: $Pr[y_{t}=1]=x_{1}$, $Pr[y_{t}=2]=x_{2}$, $Pr[y_{t}=3]=1-x_{1}-x_{2}$

I don't know the formula for $p(y_{T+1}|x)$. Is it $x_{1}^{y_{T+1}}x_{2}^{y_{T+1}}(1-x_{1}-x_{2})^{y_{T+1}}$? What should be the next steps in the integration of $p(y_{T+1}|y)=\int_{x}p(y_{T+1}|x)p(x|y)dx$?

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: So, $x \sim Dir(\alpha)$, and $y$ is what, a multinomial distribution or something else?

Comment: y is the data. So $x|y∼Dir(\alpha)$